# Tell sscanf to consider \0 as a valid character to read

Tags: c, linux

I am parsing a file with formatted strings. Need some help with parsing.
Consider below example.

```
int main()
{
    char value[32], name[32];
    int buff_ret1, buff_ret2;
    char *buff = "1000000:Hello";
    char *buff_other ="200000:\0";
    buff_ret1 = sscanf(buff,"%[^:]:%s", value, name);
    printf("buff_ret1 is %d\n", buff_ret1);

    buff_ret2 = sscanf(buff_other,"%[^:]:%s", value, name);
    printf("buff_ret2 is %d\n", buff_ret2);
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting value of `buff1_ret` and and `buff2_ret` to be 2, but `buff_ret2` value is coming as 1. I understand that it is not considering NUL. Is there a way I can say to `sscanf` function to consider NUL as a character to read.

Comment: No, there is no way to make `sscanf()` behave as you want.

Comment: `NULL` is not a character.

Comment: But there's probably some way to do what you actually want if you can explain why you think you want to read `'\0'` chars from a string.

Comment: How can you know that the real null-terminated character is the `'\0'` after the `'\0'` in buff_other? There's no way to distinguish the character `'\0'` and the null-terminated character

Comment: You could rewrite `sscanf()` (don't!), or you could write your own `for`/`while` loop to scan the buffer utilizing the additional knowledge you have about the "string" - namely that it contains two 0 bytes at the end instead of the usual one, or that you know the specific byte count... But the library utilities are going to assume that the first 0 byte is the end, because that's the way they are written...

Comment: You _can_ tell `*scanf()` to scan through `'\0'` with format `"%[^:]"` which scans until a `':'` or EOF/IO error condition is encountered.  This will work for `scanf()` and `fscanf()`.  It does not work for `sscanf()` because the function quits scanning once the end of the string `'\0'` is encountered.

Comment: As to the larger problem, simply `value[0] = '\0'; name[0] = '\0'; buff_ret1 = sscanf(buff,"%31[^:]:%31s", value, name);`  As long as `buff_ret1` is 0,1, or 2, you are OK.  Or consider `strtok()`.

Comment: @ooga In C, "A byte with all bits set to 0, called the _null character_".  §5.2.1, So unless your concern is about case as in `NULL`, versus `null`, the is a null character.

Comment: @chux Well duh. But the OP was obviously referencing the NULL pointer constant, a common beginner mistake.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. From [sscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/sscanf.html)

> Reaching the end of the string in sscanf() shall be equivalent to encountering end-of-file for fscanf().

This means `\0` (end of string) is interpreted as end of file.